# I seem to be getting an error when using the react native stack navigator and im not quite sure how to resolve it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

This is the code I used to declare the navigation

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Pressable, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
```

But I end up receiving this error message:

> ```
> A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found '        ').
> To render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component' prop to 'Screen'.
> ```

Please help, I cannot figure this out and I have a project due really soon.

Comment: Please add more code as we can only see the imported modules and not the children.